# Multiple form elements in dynamic form section

Tags: php, html, forms

I am building a form where users will need to be able to add multiple 'children' and fill in details for them. Each child has multiple inputs so to keep it simple we'll say a user is trying to add 2 children and each child requires a first name and a surname.

I aim in using javascript to add the children to a list so a user can enter a first name and surname then press 'add' and this will create hidden inputs for these details. What I am struggling with is geting these form inputs to be grouped by child so effectively what I end up with will be a $_POST array like the following:

```
$_POST['child'][0]['firstname'] = 'asdads';
$_POST['child'][0]['surname'] = 'vcbcvbc';
$_POST['child'][1]['firstname'] = 'asdads';
$_POST['child'][1]['surname'] = 'vcbcvbc';
```

Is it as simple as just setting the 'name' attribute on the inputs to name="child[][firstname]" or can someone offer a suitable solution?

Comment: `Is it as simple as just setting the 'name' attribute on the inputs to name="child[][firstname]"` you tried?

Answer (score 0):

javascript:

```
var children = [[{name:value},{name:value}],[{name:value},{name:value}],....];
```

php:

```
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($_POST['children']); $i++)
{
    foreach($_POST['children'][$i] as name => value)
    {
          // process
    }
}
```

Comment: this is how I'd do it if it was just 1 field per child but as there are several fields per child I cant have <input type=text name=children[] value=firstname /> and then <input type=text name=children[] value=surname /> as this will create a record for each input rather than grouping the inputs as a child in a multi-dimensional array....